# Solve Integration

Tags: integration

> $$I = \int\frac{2\sin x+\sin 2x}{(\cos x-1)\sqrt{\cos x+\cos^2x+\cos^3x}}dx$$

I have tried for this question to solve it first I tried to separate the numerator but that doesn't work then i tried for substituting the value in the denominator but still I am not able to convert the whole function in terms of the substituted variable function. So please help me out to solve this problem.

Comment: I've converted your question to our preferred [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) format. Please double-check whether I've done so correctly.

Comment: yeah it is correct thank you.

Comment: Set $\cos x=y^2$


$$I=-\int\dfrac{4(1+y^2)}{(y^2-1)\sqrt{y^2+y^4+y^6}}=-4\int\dfrac{y^2}{y^3}\cdot\dfrac{1+\dfrac1{y^2}}{\left(y-\dfrac1y\right)\sqrt{\dfrac1{y^2}+1+y^2}}$$ for $y>0$

Comment: If you are interested on a solution we get $$\frac{8 \cos (x) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3-3 \tan
   ^4\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}}{\sqrt{-\tan ^4\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-3}}\right)
   \sqrt{-\tan ^4\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-3}}{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{7 \cos (x)+2 \cos (2 x)+\cos (3
   x)+2} \sqrt{\cos (x) \sec ^4\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}}$$

Comment: Perhaps a step in the right direction, using the substitution $\frac{1+\cos x}{1-\cos x} = t$ gives us the integral $$\int \frac{2t}{\sqrt{t^4+t^3+t^2+t+1}}dt$$

Comment: @NinadMunshi. May be I am mistaken but I think it is simpler than that. Congratulations for this change of variable.

Comment: @NinadMunshi. For sure, your expression is correct using $u=\cos(x)$. But, in my opinion, this would lead to some elliptic integral. I repeated my calculations with $\frac{1+\cos (x)}{1-\cos (x)}=t$ that you did suggest and it becomes quite simple. Could you check my results ? Thanks and cheers :-)

Comment: Thank you Sir but can u show me further more steps to reach the answer.

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner Sir can u show me further more steps to reach the answer.

Comment: Please, make me a favor and accept Ninad Munshi 's answer instead of mine. His/her answer  $I=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\tau$ is just pure beauty .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use the double angle identity $\sin2x = 2\sin x \cos x$ to get that

$$I = \int\frac{2\sin x + \sin 2x}{(\cos x - 1)\sqrt{\cos x + \cos^2 x + \cos^3 x}}dx$$ $$ = \int \frac{(1+\cos x)(-2\sin x)dx}{(1-\cos x)\sqrt{\cos x + \cos^2 x + \cos^3 x}}$$

Now the tricky part is deciding what substitution to choose. Using the substitution $$\frac{1+\cos x}{1-\cos x} = t\implies \cos x = 1 - \frac{2}{t+1}\implies -\sin x dx = \frac{2}{(t+1)^2}dt$$

we can simplify the integral. @ClaudeLeibovici caught my error in the original simplification of my substitution. The correct simplification is

$$I = \int \frac{4t}{\sqrt{3t^4-2t^2-1}}dt$$

Complete the square on the inside of the square root:

$$I =\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \int \frac{2t}{\sqrt{(t^2-\frac{1}{3})^2-\frac{4}{9}}}dt$$

Now let $$t^2 = \frac{2}{3}\cosh \tau +\frac{1}{3}\implies 2tdt = \frac{2}{3}\sinh \tau d\tau$$ which gives us the integral

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \int \frac{\frac{2}{3}\sinh \tau}{\sqrt{\frac{4}{9}\sinh^2\tau}}d\tau = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \int d\tau = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\tau$$

leaving us with an answer of

$$I = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \cosh^{-1}\left(\frac{3t^2-1}{2}\right)+C$$

Plugging back in for $x$ and utilizing $1-\cos x = 2\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ we get our final answer:

$$I = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \cosh^{-1}\left(\frac{1+4\cos(x)+\cos^2(x)}{4\sin^4\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\right)+C$$

Comment: This $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\tau$ is pure beauty !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you for the kind words!

Comment: Starting an infinite loop : I thank you for thanking me ! Back to serious, you had a great idea and the final solution $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\tau$ is not ... too bad (joke). I wrote it in my records. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 3):

After Ninad Munshi 's comment, using
$$\frac{1+\cos (x)}{1-\cos (x)}=t \implies x=\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{t-1}{t+1}\right)\implies dx=-\frac{dt}{(t+1)\sqrt{t} }$$ the integral becomes
$$I=\int\frac{4 t}{\sqrt{3 t^4-2 t^2-1}}\,dt$$ Now $u=t^2$
$$I=2\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{3 u^2-2 u-1}}=\frac{2 }{\sqrt{3}}\log \left(1-3u-\sqrt{9 u^2-6 u-3}\right)$$

Have a look at formula $2.261$ in *"Table of Integrals, Series, and Products"*
(seventh edition) by I.S. Gradshteyn and I.M. Ryzhik.

Comment: +1 I can't count today since I thought 3=4! Good job

Comment: @NinadMunshi. All credit is for you ! Did you notice the monster given by a CAS in the comments ? Cheers.

Comment: I did, it was quite scary. I posted an answer down below that looks nice in terms of inverse hyperbolics and gets that $\frac{x}{2}$ term in the CAS answers as well. Have a look!

Comment: @NinadMunshi you thought $3=24$? ;)

Comment: Last integral should match my answer, since we both had u = cot(x/2)^4.  I think the problem is dx = -dt / (|1+t| sqrt(t)) ≠ -dt / ((1+t) sqrt(t))

Comment: @albertchan. You are, more than likely, correct.

Answer (score 0):

Let $t = \tan{x\over2}, \;dt ={1\over2} \sec^2({x\over2})dx= {1\over2} (1+t^2) dx$

$$I = \int {-8\over  t\sqrt{3-2t^4-t^8}} dt$$

Let $s = t^4, \;ds= 4t^3dt= \large{4s\over t} dt$

$$I = \int {-2\over s\sqrt{3-2s-s^2}} ds = {2\over\sqrt3}
\log\left({3-s+\sqrt{9-6s-3s^2}\over s}\right)$$

If we let $u = \cot^4({x\over2})$, it simplified a bit:

$$I = {2\over\sqrt3}\log(3u-1+\sqrt{9u^2-6u-3})$$

---

We could simplify more, by letting $w = \large{3u-1 \over 2}$

$$I = {2\over\sqrt3}\log(2w + 2\sqrt{w^2-1}) = {2\over\sqrt3}\cosh^{-1}w + {2\log2\over\sqrt3}$$

Drop the constant of integration, we get

$$I = {2\over\sqrt3}\cosh^{-1}\left({3(\cot{x\over2})^4-1 \over 2}\right)$$